# Nokogiri and Rails - Small Issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

I'm using Nokogiri to parse this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GetPropertiesResponse>
 <Properties>
  <Property>
   <Id>19</Id>
   <Name>Property 1</Name>
   <Breakfast></Breakfast>
   <Currency>GBP</Currency>
  </Property>

  <Property>
   <Id>13</Id>
   <Name>Property 2</Name>
   <Breakfast>IN</Breakfast>
   <Currency>EUR</Currency>
  </Property>

  <Property>
   <Id>15</Id>
   <Name>Property 3</Name>
   <Breakfast>EX</Breakfast>
   <Currency>GBP</Currency>
  </Property>

 </Properties>
</GetPropertiesResponse>
```

like this:

```
...
doc = Nokogiri::XML(response.body)
@property = doc.xpath("//Property")
```

and then in my view I'm displaying each property name like so:

```
<%= @property.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.xpath("Name").text %><br>
<% end %>
```

but my output always has a mysterious `0` on the end and I'm not sure why? My output looks like this:

```
Property 1
Property 2
Property 3
0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This

```
<%= @property.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.xpath("Name").text %><br>
<% end %>
```

Has an extra `=` sign

It should be:

```
<% @property.each do |item| %>
  <%= item.xpath("Name").text %><br>
<% end %>
```

The 0 is because when `@property.each` completes it returns 0 if you remove the `=` the return value is not shown